# Building multi-level menu for wordpress utilizing css transitions and transforms. Issue: does not work in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm developing a three level menu and it's working great! -- unfortunately IE has no support for pointer-events or css transforms.

Here's the menu code -- It's set up to look like a wordpress menu >>> wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Menu Name' ));

```
<nav class="main">
    <ul>
        <li class="current-menu-ancestor"><a href="#link">A</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#link">A1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#link">A1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">A1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">A1-3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">A1-4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#link">A2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#link">A2-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">A2-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">A2-3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">A2-4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#link">B</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#link">B1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#link">B1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">B1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">B1-3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">B1-4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">B1-5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">B1-6</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">B1-7</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">B1-8</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#link">B2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#link">B2-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">B2-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">B2-3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">B2-4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#link">B3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#link">B3-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#link">B3-2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I tossed in a bit of jquery to move the "current-menu-ancestor" class around in the fiddle.

```
$( document ).ready(function($) {
    $('nav > ul > li > a').hover( function(){
        $('nav > ul > li').removeClass('current-menu-ancestor');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current-menu-ancestor');
    });
});
```

And of course, the CSS that handles the style and behaviors:

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    paddding: 0;
    background: rgba(140,142,144,1);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/* ========== Overall Nav Styles ========== */
nav ul {display:none;z-index:999;}

nav a {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}

/* ========== Frist Level ========== */
nav.main > ul {
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style:none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: rgba(250,252,255,1);
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

nav.main > ul > li { float:left;border-right: 1px solid rgba(80,82,84,.1);}
nav.main > ul > li:last-child {border: none;}
nav.main > ul > li > a {
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: rgba(80,82,84,1);
}


nav.main > ul > li > a:hover { color: rgba(0,142,184,1);}

nav.main > ul > li > a:hover { color: rgba(0,142,184,1);}


/* ========== Second Level ========== */
nav.main > ul > li > ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style:none;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(100,102,105,1);
    font-size: .875rem;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;

    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    display:block;

    background: rgba(100,102,105,1);
    pointer-events:none;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform:perspective(500) rotateX(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
}

nav.main > ul > li.current-menu-ancestor > ul {
    pointer-events:auto;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform:perspective(500) rotateX(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
}

nav.main > ul > li > ul > li { float:left;border-right: 1px solid rgba(200,202,204,.1);}
nav.main > ul > li > ul > li:last-child {border: none;}
nav.main > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: rgba(200,202,204,1);
}
nav.main > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover { color: rgba(255,142,0,1); }


/* ========== Third Level ========== */
nav.main > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 55px 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style:none;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(60,62,65,1);
    font-size: .75rem;

    pointer-events:none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform:perspective(500) rotateX(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
}

nav.main > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li { float:left; width: 25% }

nav.main > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    height: 120px;
    line-height: 120px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: rgba(250,252,254,1);
}
nav.main > ul > li.current-menu-ancestor > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover {
    color: rgba(142,255,240,1);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

/* ========== Drawer Animation ========== */
nav.main > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
    pointer-events:auto;
    padding: 30px 0;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform:perspective(500) rotateX(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
}
```

I searched out several similar questions and most of them are about positioning or broken css.

I did find a partial solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590578/css-drop-down-menu-not-working-in-internet-explorer

They used a simple "display:block/display:none" switch instead of transitions. This is good for preventing a person from interacting with an invisible menu item, but takes away any sort of animation.

As I mentioned early on, support for transforms and pointer-events are the heart of this issue. If pointer-events worked in IE, I would be able to use 2d transitions or a simple opacity change. I had also tried a height change, but these trays need to have a dynamic height for wrapping menu items. Setting the height to 100% or auto didn't work.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/juicedesigns/9ggrt/

Worst case is that I'll just have to set up a non-animated fallback style for ie, but I thought I'd go ahead and pose the question in case someone had a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to resort to the separate style for IE to give this cross browser support.

Things changed a bit between the original post and what I have now, but here's the general idea:

Detect IE and call specific CSS file:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wp-content/themes/theme/css/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Force some things with !important, and set up a simple block/none display switch in ie.css:

```
header nav ul ul ul {
width: 100% !important;
margin: 0 !important;
padding: 0 !important;
}

header nav ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    display:none;
}

header nav ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

It doesn't have fluid animations on IE, but it works back to version 9. Since 11 dropped support for conditional statements it won't be able to see this css file, fortunately it has better support for the new css features I employed.